# WSL cannot upgrade to WSL2 as Class Not Registered error arises

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've been trying to get Docker up and running but it keeps shutting down because the WSL needed should be version 2, but when I try to set WSL to version 2 it keeps throwing this error:

> Class not registered
> Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

I have unistalled WSL, reinstalled it and updated it using the Powershell(admin). I have enabled the Virtual Machine Platform. When I try to set the version to 2, that's when it goes back to the same error.

`wsl.exe --update` outputs:

> Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
> Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.

`wsl --set-default-version 2` outputs:

> Class not registered
> Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Answer (score 2):

I found out this is an ongoing problem as of Dec 2023. I solved it by manually downloading the latest MSI release and installing it [WSL releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases).

Do not run

```
wsl.exe --update

wsl --set-default-version 2
```

Just manually installing the latest version solved it for me.